# How to stop a ListBoxItem from being selected if the data related to the previous one is incorrect?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a `ListBox` which when clicked displays data to the user. If the user enters invalid data and they click another item in the list I want to prevent the `ListBoxItem` they clicked from being selected. However, currently the `ListBoxItem_Selected` event is firing *after* the `ListBoxItem` is being selected, so I don't know how to stop the next list box item from being selected.

In the `ListBoxItem_Selected` event, I'm validating the data but by this point it's too late.

Simply executing

```
((ListBoxItem)this.ListBox.Items[previousIndex]).IsSelected = true;
```

or

```
this.ListBox.SelectedIndex = previousIndex;
```

does not work, i.e. the next list item is still selected.

How can I prevent the next item from being selected if the data they entered is invalid?

Comment: http://www.chintanparmar.com/Blog/Details?BlogID=33 seems like what your looking for (something to revert the SelectionChanged if some required logic is not successful) just switch the TabControl to your ListBox from the article

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to do this would be to Bind the Listbox enabled to a bool in your code.

Something like this

```
public bool enabledOrNot { get; set; }

<Listbox isEnabled={Binding enabledOrNot}>...
```

Then when you do the validation on your first input you can set this bool and it will enable or disable as needed.

Another way to do this would be to use ValidationRules. I know we use these in our code at work but they are to arcane for me to understand. All I know is they somehow validate before anything else takes place. Its a built in .NET feature

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validationrules.aspx